# Concrete5 show fancybox from file set on link click?

Tags: php, fancybox, concrete5, fileset

I don't know exactly where to start to display files from the file set in order to show a fancybox gallery on click. I would like to have the gallery open from a link. On click show the gallery, aka images that have the same rel but are set to display:none (easily controlled by my css). I can do it from selecting one image but am not sure how to pass the images from the file set into the view (I'm assuming I need to create some kind of function in my controller to get the fsID, just not sure how). I just need the first image to display on the page (thumbnail image), then click the link and it shows more full size images.

Basically, if you know Concrete5, I would like it to be like the image block, except that the administrator can choose a fileset instead of one image.

here is my view.php

```
$picture = $this->controller->getPicture();
if ($picture) {
    $bigPicture = $image->getThumbnail($picture,600,600)->src;
    $smallPicture = $image->getThumbnail($picture,200,200)->src;

    echo "<img src=" . $smallPicture . " alt=" . $imageTitle . " title=" . $imageTitle . "/>";//thumbnail picture
echo "<div id=\"image-modal\">";
echo "<a href=" . $bigPicture . " class=\"fancybox-thumb\" rel=" . $title . " title=" . $imageTitle . ">{$linkText}</a>";//open fancybox from link
echo "<div class=\"hiddenGallery\"  style=\"display:none;\">";//hidden images
    echo "<a href=\"images/pattern/t-103-n.jpg\" class=\"fancybox-thumb\" rel=" . $title . " title=" . $imageTitle . ">";
echo "<img src=\"images/pattern/t-103-n.jpg\" class=\"fancybox-thumb\" />";
echo "</a>";
    echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
}
```

my controller.php

```
function getPicture() {
        if ($this->fIDpicture > 0) {
            return File::getByID($this->fIDpicture);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

my add.php

```
$al = Loader::helper('concrete/asset_library');
echo $al->image('ccm-b-image', 'fIDpicture', t('Choose File'),
    $this->controller->getPicture());
echo '</div>';
```

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, two things :

- You have to set the `class="fancybox-thumb"` AND the `rel` attribute to the `<a>` tag!!, not to the `<img />` tag.
- If you are planing to hide the rest of the elements of the gallery, don't set a `display: none;` css property to each of them, but rather wrap them in a hidden `<div>` container like :

  ```
  <div style="display: none;">
    <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gallery" href="images/02.jpg"></a>
    <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gallery" href="images/03.jpg"></a>
    <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gallery" href="images/04.jpg"></a>
    ... etc
  </div>
  ```

I am using the rendered html, which is what it matters.

Comment: Mmm yes, I missed those finer details while I was focused on how to get the images to show in the first place. Thank you for the pointers!

Answer (score 0):

I have some code which handles the entire back-end (add/edit/controller) part of this equation:
https://github.com/jordanlev/c5_designer_gallery

Here's a tutorial that explains how to use it (with the example of the FlexSlider, but if you know how Fancybox works then it shouldn't be hard to understand what's going on):
http://c5blog.jordanlev.com/blog/2011/12/build-a-slideshow-block/